# D3.js Transition issue

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, html5-canvas, transition

I am learning D3.js and it seems quite easy, well.. so far until this transition came up.

I want to make the rectangle bars **animate their width**, but all they are doing is the color is changing.

I can't quite understand what i am doing wrong.

Here's my **JavaScript**

```
var dataArray = [20, 30, 40, 60];
dataArray2 = [20, 40, 60];
dataPosition = [0, 300, 600];
width = 500;
height = 500;

var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 60])
    .range([0, width]);

var axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .ticks(5)
    .scale(widthScale);

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 60])
    .range(["hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)", "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)"]);

var canvas = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)");


var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr("width", function (d) {
    return widthScale(d);
})
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
    return colorScale(d);
})
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
    return i * 100;
})


canvas.append("g")
    .call(axis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,400)");
```

**[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAG2r/22/)**

Is it also possible for numbers to be iterated on the rectangles along the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta first set the value to zero, then add the transition code the delay time and then the finally set the actual value

http://jsfiddle.net/M8TXZ/1/

```
var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataArray)
   .enter().append("rect")
   .transition()
   .duration(1500)
   .attr("height", 50)
   .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return colorScale(d);
   })
   .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return i * 100;
   })
   //Sets the width to zero
   .attr("width", function(d) {
      return 0;
   })
   .transition()
   .duration(1000)
   //Sets the width to the actual value
   .attr("width", function(d) {
      return widthScale(d);
   })
```